# Write "?" in a string if a property is null

Tags: c#, datetime, string-formatting, tostring

How can I write the Startedate like "?" is Startdate is null

```
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Format("Course {0} ({1} is an {2} course, will be given by {3}, starts on {4}, costs {5:0.00} and will have maximum {6} participants"
        , Name
        , CourseId
        , CourseType
        , Teacher
        , (StartDate == null ? "?" : StartDate)
        , Price
        , MaximumParticipants);
}
```

Comment: Change it to `(StartDate == null ? "?" : StartDate.ToString())`

Comment: A ternary statement requires the same type in both operands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could tweak your existing code

```
(StartDate == null ? "?" : StartDate.ToString())
```

Or leverage `Nullable<T>` `.HasValue`

```
(StartDate.HasValue ? StartDate.ToString() : "?")
```

The point is, `?:` requires the same type for both conditions.

Answer (score 7):

Both sides of the [ternery operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) need to be the same type. From the documentation:

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

So you can simply convert your date to a string (note the formatting is up to you):

```
(StartDate == null ? "?" : StartDate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))
```

Comment: Aah oke I see, Because StartDate is DateTime and "?" is a String

Comment: `StartDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")` will not work. I needs to be: `StartDate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`. But why is the extra formatting required at all?

Comment: @MartinMulder Actually it will work. The formatting I put in there as an example, it's up to the OP to choose how to display it.

Comment: because your return type is String and you are building one in yor return statement your true and false value of the ternery operator  should also both be String

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren Exactly yes. I'll edit to add clarification.

Comment: @DavigG: `StartDate` is of type `Nullable<DateTime>`. `Nullable<T>` does not have a ToString-overload with formatting capabilities. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hd15ket(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 7):

C# 6 lets you write this without ternary operator, like this:

```
StartDate?.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") ?? "?"
```

`?.` will conditionally execute `ToString` only if `StartDate` is not `null`. Null coalesce operator `??` will complete the job by providing `"?"` string as a replacement for `null` value.

You can go further and replace `String.Format` with interpolating string, like this:

```
return $"Course {Name} ({CourseId} is an {CourseType} course, will be given by {Teacher}, starts on {StartDate?.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") ?? "?"}, costs {Price:0.00} and will have maximum {MaximumParticipants} participants";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use IsNullOrEmpty() function it will cover null or empty date
(IsNullOrEmpty(StartDate) ? "?" : StartDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))